# Annotating a seaborn swarmplot with a line

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have created a swarmplot and I want to add lines on the plot like so:

[image]

I want the locations of these lines to represent a value on the y-axis. Is there a way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this using [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = {
    'A': [23,53,23,52,52,78],
    'B': [45,78,68,68,79,79],
    'C': [3,46,24,57,76,13]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

graph = sns.swarmplot(x="variable", y="value", data=df.melt())
graph.axhline(50, xmin=0.065, xmax=0.265)
graph.axhline(30, xmin=0.40, xmax=0.60)
graph.axhline(70, xmin=0.735, xmax=0.935)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the line is behind the plotted points. Is there any way to plot the lines over the plotted points?

Comment: @AryaMan Yes, add `zorder=0` to your swarmplot.